# A question concerning boundaries of semi-Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I am reading a proof and one line says *"As $M$ has no boundary..."* . To the best of my knowledge, all we know about $M$ is that it is a compact semi-Riemannian manifold with constant (sectional) curvature.

I was quite puzzled and starting wondering whether it was due to the constant curvature, but I didn't really get anywhere.

Do the before mentioned properties of $M$ imply that it doesn't have a boundary, or could it simply be that when not explicitly saying $M$ *a manifold with boundary* we assume $M$ not to have a boundary?

Comment: Many authors define differentiable manifolds to have no boundary. Most likely, the authr(s) of the text you are reading do the same.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I see, thanks.